# Java 8 - Stream with Objects and primitive wrappers

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am working with java 8 stream and trying to modify the object content in the forEach terminal operation.

The issues which i am facing here is that i am able to modify the `List<Employee>` object contents but not able to modify the contents of `List<Integer>`

The code snippet is as follows:

```
public static void streamExample() {

    List<Employee> listEmp = Arrays.asList(new Employee());
    listEmp.stream().forEach(a -> a.setEmptName("John Doe"));
    listEmp.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    List<Integer> listInteger = Arrays.asList(2, 4, 6, 8, 12,17, 1234);
    listInteger.stream().filter(v -> v % 2 == 0).forEach(a -> a=a+1);
    listInteger.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

}
```

I am wondering the change is not reflecting back in the list because of  unboxing the Integer object while performing the `a=a+1` operation but not sure.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the element types. An operation like `forEach(a -> a=a+1)` never makes sense, as you are only modifying the *parameter* `a`. In Java, modifying a parameter variable has no effect on the caller. This principle is also known as “pass by value”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use not optimal approach of `Stream`. Do think of each step in `Stream` as modify existed (or create new) element and return it back to the `Stream`. Finally you receive `final` result and you can use one of `final` method to finalize (and actually run the whole stream working) the `Stream`:

```
List<Integer> listInteger = Arrays.asList(2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 17, 1234);
listInteger.stream().filter(v -> v % 2 == 0).forEach(a -> a = a + 1);
listInteger.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Here you have initial array. You want to do following:

1. Filter out some elements (this is not `final` step);
2. Print filtered elements out (this is `final` step).

To do so, you do not have to create `Streams` two times. Do use one:

```
Stream.of(2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 17, 1234)    // create stream (there're many way to do it)
      .filter(v -> v % 2 == 0)         // filter out required elements
      .map(v -> v + 1)                 // transform elements using given rule
      .forEach(System.out::println);   // finalize stream with printing out each element separately
```

**Note:** `Stream.of(...)` creates a `Stream`, then we add two steps to the stream `filter` and `map` and then `finalize` or **START** created stream with `forEach`.

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning a new value to a local variable (`a`), so that has no affect on the source of the second `Stream` (your `List<Integer>`). Note that this is not what you are doing with your `List<Employee>`, where you are calling a setter method to mutate the elements of the `List`.

Since `Integer`s are immutable, you can't mutate the elements of your input `List<Integer>`.

Instead, you can create a new `List`:

```
List<Integer> newList = 
    listInteger.stream()
               .map(v -> v % 2 == 0 ? v + 1 : v)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or you can stream over the indices of your `List`, and replace some of the elements of that `List`:

```
IntStream.range(0,listInteger.size())
         .filter(i -> listInteger.get(i) % 2 == 0)
         .forEach(i -> listInteger.set(i, listInteger.get(i + 1));
```